# Categories are not in order same as in Admin panel Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sorting, sub-categories

I am listing children categories of specific category using below code:

```
$categoryFactory = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
$category = $categoryFactory->loadByAttribute('url_key', 'shop');
$childrenCategories = $category->getAllChildren(true);
```

This method does not return categories in the same order as in the Admin panel.

I have changed the position of categories in Admin panel by drag and drop then I cleared cache and reindexed too.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me:

```
$categoryFactory = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
$category = $categoryFactory->loadByAttribute('url_key', 'shop');

$childrenCategoryids = $this->getAllChildren($category);
$childcategories = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create() 
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $childrenCategoryids)) 
->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
```

Main point is `setOrder('position', 'ASC')`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
$categoryFactory = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection();
$category = $categoryFactory->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key','shop');
$childrenCategories = $category->getAllChildren(true);
```

Comment: It's giving error: ````Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor::addAttributeToFilter````

Comment: which model call for get category collection ???

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Error: ````Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection::getAllChildren()````

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection();
$categorys = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', 'shop')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$childrenCategories = $categorys->getAllChildren(true);
$cat_id = $category->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();
$category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($cat_id);
$childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
```

Comment: It gives error:  ````Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection::getChildrenCategories()````

Comment: try now i have updated my code @Khushbu

Comment: Error: ````Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection::getAllChildren()````

Comment: @Khushbu you have use above category factory?

Comment: yes. i am using   \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory

Comment: @Khushbu i have updated my answer it is working code for me

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
<?php 
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
$catId = $category->getId(); //you can add your desired category ID
$subCat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
$subCats = $subCat->getChildrenCategories();
echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($subCats as $category) {
        $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category->getId());
        echo "<li>";
        echo $subcategory-getName();
        echo "</li>";       
    }
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Hope this helps you solve your problem